# Simple HTML dom, getting xpath of found element

Tags: dom, selenium

I was wondering if there is a way to get xpath of an element found using simple HTML DOM? Or something like CSS path?

I'm using Selenium with Simple HTML DOM to scan a page's form and submit it, however sometimes submit button does not have a name, class or ID, so xpath or CSS selector are really my only choice, could anyone suggest a solution?

Comment: Have you tried using Firebug to get xpath?

Comment: I need to get it via the PHP class, I can get it via firebug easily but it's not a choice in my case.